# Install IIS 7 and .Net 4.0 on windows 10

Tags: iis, windows-10, .net-framework-version

I have a software, which requires IIS 7 or above and .Net framework 4.0 or above installed.

I know Windows 10 has IIS 10 and .Net 4.6 built in and I ticked all the components available in Program and Features. But the software still failed to validate the environment.

Is there any way I can install the older version of IIS and/or .Net on Windows 10 PC instead of rebuilding the system with Windows 7?

Thank you.

Comment: Ping the vendor of that software. You don't have other options if you don't own the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution without modifying the software.

What I did was modifying the computer's registry for IIS and .Net

1.Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->InetStp

- Update MajorVersion Data value to 8
- Update SetupString Data value to IIS 8.5
- Update VersionString Data value to Version 8.5

2.Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->NET Framework Setup->NDP->v4

3.Change the Version Data value from all the subfolders from 4.6.00079 to a lower version, for exampple 4.5.51650 for .Net 4.5, do these for all 4 folders, Client, Client->1033, Full and Full->1033

4.Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Wow6432Node->Microsoft, repeat step 2 and 3 for all the related folders. (This is for updating the 64bit part of the IIS and .Net, if you are on a 32bit machine, ignore this step)

5.After complete, install the software, you should be fine.

Comment: when i try to do Step 3 it says "Cant edit Version: Error writing the value's new contents"

Comment: Radhi, you need to also grant permission for these registry folders:
a. Grant full access permission to Client and 1033 folder(do the same for Full and 1033 folder)
 i. Right client the folder
 ii. Choose Advanced at the bottom
 iii. Click Change on the top, next to owner
 iv. Search for your domain account
 v. Apply and OK
 vi. At the Permission for Client window, add your domain account with Full Control and Read permission
 vii. Apply and OK

Comment: Hey! I am having the same problem on my windows 10 laptop. I tried your approach, but in vain. Could you suggest any other method for dealing with the version constraint.

Comment: Maybe using a Windows 7 VM on your windows 10 if my solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to run the web app directly on Windows 10, you can also use a virtual machine (e.g. older version of Windows running in Hyper-V or VMWare) to run on IIS7.

Hopefully, you can reach out to the vendor soon to update their application to run on IIS7 or higher.

Comment: Thank you Shahed, the software is definitely working fine on Windows 7 and also Windows 8 or 8.1 I think, so I guess that's IIS7/7.5 or higher and .Net 4.0 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly to allow me to install web farm into IIS.  IIS was 10 but each server farm was not loaded when I enabled it from turn on/off windows features.

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`->`SOFTWARE`->`Microsoft`->`InetStp`

and change the following:

1. Update MajorVersion Data value    (a) to 8
2. Update SetupString Data value (10) to IIS 8.5
3. Update VersionString Data value (Version 10) to Version 8.5

This allowed me to install web farm from the Web Platform installer without getting the following error:

> *you need to be on IIS 7.0 or higher...*

Thanks